# Update column values from list to postgres using Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to update column values of species table from list values using python. I converted list to tuple:

```
tu=[(3,), (4,), (0,), (0,), (4,), (4,), (2,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (3,), (0,), (0,), (4,), (2,), (0,), (2,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (1,)]
```

Below is my database table

[image]

I want to update values from speciesID =1

My python code is:

```
cur.executemany('update species set listvalues = %s ', tu)
```

I'm not getting any errors, but values are not being updated. Please help!

Comment: What is the type of `listvalues`?

Comment: original list values are integers i.e l=[0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4]

Comment: The `update` is missing a `WHERE` clause‽  And I'm not sure I understand what you want as a result. `listvalues` (plural) is a strange name for a single integer value. Have you `commit()`ed the changes?